# Recognize letters written with symbols

Tags: parsing

I have a bit of an unorthodox question that I cannot think of an approach how to tackle. I have some letters written like this:

```
   /\     |---\    /---\
  /  \    |___/   |
 /----\   |   \   |
/      \  |___/    \---/
```

Now, the idea is to read this content (possibly from a text file) and parse it to the real letters they actually represent. So this should be parsed to `ABC`.

I understand this is not OCR, but I have no idea if something like that is possible. I am not asking for a solution, but rather, how would you best attack this problem? What would be a good criteria for distinguishing when a 'letter' starts and when does it end?

Comment: Are the letter representations always the same? (ie. does the symbol for A always look like the one you show with the same number of characters) if so then the problem is relatively easy, if not then it gets more complicated

Comment: For the beginning, I think it's safe to assume the letters are going to always look the same. But still - you are always reading line by line, doesn't that make it quite tricky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments it sounds like you could store a character font map (2-dimensional array for each character) and then read the input file and buffer a number of lines equal to the height of the characters.

Then, for each group of lines you would want to segment the input based on the width of the characters and slide across horizontally, looking for matches against your font map.

If you need to support multiple fonts then things get more complicated and you'd benefit more from a neural-net approach to character recognition of sorts.

One important aspect to keep in mind about how OCR typically works is that it takes an arbitrary image and it "pixelates" it generating a much lower resolution image. In your case you've already got a "pixelated" representation of the image and all you'd have to do is read in the input and feed that into the rest of the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I would still approach this as an OCR-esque problem.

You could first draw the characters onto an image and run it through an available OCR library.

Or you could do it yourself.
Pre-process it by converting vertical and horzitonal characters into lines first.

Then where there are forward and backslashes, approximate start and finish points of the curve by where they meet the previous horizontal and vertical (a different approach would be needed for letters such as 'o' or 'e').

Once you have this image a simple pattern analysis approach, such as naive bayes should be able to produce reliable results.

Whether the pre processing would actually provide accuracy improvements, i'm not sure